# In Sitecore SXA how do I change the datasource from page for a rendering that belongs to partial design?

Tags: sxa

We want content authors to edit content on the page without having to add the rendering each time on the page level. For this we are thinking of partial design.Our blog partial design needs fields like title,description,image, tags which are on page level and a promo(reusable). These fields are may not be editable on page level once we add to partial design.

How do I change datasource on page level if its shared?
How do I make sure the data is pulled from the page level for the rest of the fields?

Comment: How did you place those fields on that partial? Which rendering did you use?

Comment: For the promo , I used the out of box SXA promo rendering.For the rest of the fields I am planning to have these fields on the page level. Is it possible to create one rendering that pulls these three fields and maps the respective fields.

Comment: Planning? So you haven't even tried it yet?? Just asking as I don't see your problem.. and fields on page level won't need a datasource.

Comment: What about promo? If I were to change datasource on every page?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create one rendering that pulls these three fields and maps the respective fields

It is easier than you think.

There is a rendering called: **Page Content**. The main goal of this rendering is to display fields from Context item.

Once you add it you can select **Rendering Variant** (this tells rendering which fields should be displayed)

[image]

Of course you can define your own **Rendering Variants** (`/sitecore/content/tenant/site/Presentation/Rendering Variants/Page Content`)

[image]

### Read more:

- [The SXA renderings and rendering variants](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/the_sxa_renderings_and_rendering_variants#_Page_content_1)
- [Create a rendering variant](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/create_a_rendering_variant)

If you want to test all renderings I recommend you to check [XA.Reference](https://github.com/alan-null/XA.Reference). It contains all renderings preconfigured so you can get better feeling how to use each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your fields won't be a problem as that information is not embedded in the rendering - so you should be able to have editable fields within the partial design.

For the promo, I don't think it is possible as you cannot alter the rendering information from the partial design on the page. And a datasource is part of the rendering data.