# SXA Event Detail page

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA Event rendering on my page, I add create Event list and used it for listing and calendar, however, we cant find Event detail page, how to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my structure:

- Home Page - I've placed Event List rendering on it
- Sitecore Symposium 2017 Page - under the Home I've just one page which is containing details about event
- Sitecore Events - event list data source with just one event underneath

I look like this:

[image]

Now, let's open the Home page where the Event List rendering is placed:

[image]

Link to the page with details is in the bottom right corner.

Remember that Event List is using [Rendering Variants](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/create_a_rendering_variant) to render events - so you can modify this as you want. Here is the default variant shipped with SXA. I've market item responsible for generating a link to details page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, I have question-related to page "Sitecore Symposium 2017 Page" how its render the content of the event, are you adding custom code to render it

Comment: The page has nothing to do with event item - it's just a separate page with additional pieces of information about the event.

Comment: ok what if i had a lot of events, it will be hard for the user to create item under content tree and in event data source , so is there a workaround like a single page for event detail for example /event/[EventName]/[EventID] and we use custom code to fitch the event detail fro it

Comment: Add Page Content rendering and point it data source to the event item stored under Data folder.

Comment: So based on “https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5074/in-sitecore-sxa-how-do-i-change-the-datasource-from-page-for-a-rendering-that-be” 
the Page content can read from current Context, what I was trying to do is to create two pages “Event Listing page” and each event on this page links to using “Event Details link” property  “Event Details Page” , I place “Page Content” in “Event Details Page” and create a variant to display event title ,…  , it does work I guess because the context is not correct so can you help me to fill in the gaps?

Comment: hi , appreciate your feedback

Comment: You only need to change Datasource item of the Page Content. Simply point to certain event item (from under the Data folder)

Comment: is there a way to make it dynamic, so I don't have to point to a specific event, so the event detail page contains Page Content which renders event based on query string, rather than pointing to certain event item